# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"CRS"’

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a raster in WGS 1984 coordinate system with the pixel values denoting categorical values i.e. the raster is a land use land cover raster, with each value meaning water bodies, ice, forest etc.

I need to convert it to the unamed ellipse sinusoidal projection (with a linear unit of meters), since my remaining rasters are in this projection. I have tried-

```
projectRaster(raster in WGS 1984 system, crs(raster in sinusoidal projection), method='ngb' since my raster is categorical as mentioned above).
```

I get this error message- Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"CRS"’.

In context to this question, what does the error message mean and how do I solve it such that the projection works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help for `projectRaster` looks like this:

```
 projectRaster(from, to, res, crs, method="bilinear", 
              alignOnly=FALSE, over=FALSE, filename="", ...)
```

When you do `projectRaster(r1, r2)` it matches the `from` and `to` arguments, and the `to` argument has to be:

```
 to: Raster* object with the parameters to which 'from' should be
      projected
```

a `raster` object. But you fed it `crs(raster object)`. You don't need to use `crs` if you have a raster, you can feed it the two rasters:

```
 r3 = projectRaster(r1, r2)
```

should work. If you only have a crs object, you have to name the parameter so it matches the `crs` argument rather than the `to` argument:

```
cc = crs(r2)
r3 = projectRaster(r1, crs=cc)
```

should also work.